# RTrim blank spaces for an entire column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to trim blank spaces on the right of cell contents for an entire column in Excel.  I've learned that I can use RTrim in VBA to accomplish this. I'd figured out how to make it work row by row individually with a loop.  Is there any way to make it work on an whole selected column in one fell swoop?
Here is the code I have gathered so far.  But like I said, it'd be nice if this could be reworded / recoded to do the entire column at one time:

```
enter code here   Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
ApplicationScreenUpdating = False
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
Columns("A:A").Select

   
Dim result As String
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
  If (Right(Cells(i, "A").Value, 4)) Like "    " Or (Right(Cells(i, "A").Value, 3)) Like "   " Then
    Cells(i, "A") = RTrim$(Cells(i, "A"))
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I've tried to attach a picture of what the data looks like with the spaces underlined to be well seen ... not sure if that worked.   Thanks for any help someone can give.  And if not the entire column ... maybe some simpler way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not.  The TRIM functions (RTRIM, LTRIM, TRIM, etc) accepts strings values only.  Meaning there is no other way than looping through the range and applying the trim function to each string individually.

Comment: Well, goodness.  Thank you for verifying.  I did actually test it with a large amount of rows and even with >5,000 rows, it takes less than 12 seconds, so that'll work.   I'll stick with this then.  Thanks again!